# Selenium - How to add same product to cart many times

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml

i have been trying to find a way to add the same product to cart 3 times but it's not working, are you able to tell me what i am missing. As you can see, i am getting the elements through *Page Object Pattern* and importing to the test class.

```
    '''
        import java.util.List;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
        import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;   
        import Practice1.test1.BaseClass;
        import pageObjects.CartPageObjects;

        public class ShopPage1Test extends BaseClass {

        //to invoke WebDriver and load website
            @BeforeTest()
        public void startURL() {
                globalDriver();

            }


            @Test
            public void getBase() {

       //get the single product which you want to add to cart
    WebElement product_to_add_to_cart  = CartPageObjects.get_single_product_name();


         //Get all your products in a list
                List<WebElement> all_products = CartPageObjects.get_All_Products();

            //Get all Products count
     int products_count = CartPageObjects.get_All_Products().size();

            //iterate through products list     
                for(int i=0; i<products_count;i++) {
                    if(all_products.get(i).equals(product_to_add_to_cart)) {

  //click add to cart element if product found in index
    int a=0;
   //iterate 3 times and click element
    while(a<3){                 
    a++;
        //click add to cart element
        CartPageObjects.add_to_cart_button().get(i).click();
    a=3;
    }
                }


                }


            }

            @AfterTest
            public void aftertests(){
                System.out.println("test finished");
            }

        }     
    '''
```

Comment: May be when you are clicking Add to cart for the first time, the button element you are trying to click changes its property for some seconds before coming to its normal state. My guess is you need synchronisation here. Put some waits and check.

Comment: @mkhumi, thanks a million !! thats actually the problem, i add 5 secs wait and issue was resolved
'''
for(int a = 0; a < 3; a ++) {
CartPageObjects.add_to_cart_button().get(i).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
     
    }
'''

Comment: I am glad it worked :)

Comment: One more suggestion: avoid using thread.sleep if you can. Instead use explicit waits.